# Array becoming NULL after function

Tags: c, arrays, function, file, pointers

I have a pretty standard function to read from a file. It works as expected creating the array.

```
void readInts(char fileName[], int *values) {
FILE *file;
file = fopen(fileName, "r");

int maxBagWeight, numberOfItems;
fscanf(file, "%d", &maxBagWeight);
fscanf(file, "%d", &numberOfItems);

int numbers[(numberOfItems * 2) + 2];
values = (int*) malloc(sizeof(numbers));
values[0] = maxBagWeight;
values[1] = numberOfItems;

int i = 2;
while (!feof(file)) {
    fscanf(file, "%d", &values[i]);
    i++;
}

fclose(file);
}
```

In my main:

```
int testValues[0]; //= {4, 11, 6, 2, 10, 4, 12, 6, 13, 7, 23};
    readInts(filename, testValues);

    //Number of total items
    int numberOfItems = testValues[0];
```

When I exit the function, testValues is untouched in main.

It's supposed to keep the values given in readInts function. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Remember that in C all arguments are passed *by value*, which means the value of the argument it passed into the local argument-variable inside the function. As such the pointer assignment to `values` inside the `readInts` function will only assign to the local variable, and the assignment will be lost once the function returns. Do some research about *emulating pass by reference in C* for way to solve it. Or just simply *return* the pointer.

Comment: Furthermore you define `testValues` as an *empty array*, which doesn't make any sense. Especially since arrays of any size will have a fixed address, you can't make them "point" somewhere else. You need a pointer.

Answer (score 2):

In `main`, you have `testValues` which is an array.

You pass the address of the first element of that array into `readInts`.

In `readInts`, you **assign** into the pointer parameter so that it no longer points to the array in `main`. Since the array in `main` is no longer pointed to, no further changes are made into that array.

---

Another problem: The size of the array `testValues` is zero elements. This is not allowed in standard C. Furthermore, since the size of an array doesn't change after its creation, it would be futile to expect it to gain any elements. The behaviour of accessing the element at index 0 is undefined, since that element does not exist.

Comment: I've made this in main:
`int *testValues;` and then send that pointer to the function is that what's supposed to be?

Comment: No, ended up just making what @some-programmer-dude told. I return the pointer from the function and it's working as expected